# Python Pika blocking connection on a dedicated class - callback not being call

Tags: python, flask, callback, pika

When i run a simple app (producer / consumer) - all is working. aka connecting to rabbitmq, consuming msgs etc.

when I run the below code inside a class (in order not to block the flask app) --> the callback not being called.

I added some prints and it seems that all is fine during the connection initialization.

The msgs are consumed (the queue is is being clean) --> but the callback is not even being called.
Any idea ?
TIA

here is the code:

```
currentprices = ({"1":5.5, "2":3.5})

def initialparams(): #being called from outside
    print('S-init')
    RMQ = RMQPriceListener()
    RMQ.create_currentprices_channel()
    print('F-init')


class RMQPriceListener():
    def create_currentprices_channel(self):
        try:
            credential_params = pika.PlainCredentials('un', 'pw')
            connection_params = pika.ConnectionParameters(
                                host='127.0.0.1',port=5555,
                                credentials=credential_params) # i use port 5555

            connection = pika.BlockingConnection(connection_params)
            channel = connection.channel()
            channel.queue_declare(queue='formatedrates')
            print('c0') # being printed
            channel.basic_consume(queue='formatedrates',
                                  on_message_callback=self.callback,
                                  auto_ack=True) # without this (above) self - the app 
                                                 #  is stuck here (which is logical) 
            print('c1') # being printed
            channel.start_consuming() # working good and cleaning the queue

            return  ('lost connection to RMQ')
        except:
            return ('No connection to RMQ')
```

** the problematic func that works good on regular app but here inside the class not**

```
 def callback(ch, method, properties,msg):
       print(f'msg={msg}')     # never printed
       global currentprices    # has an initial value and being call from the below  
                                 getcurrentrates method and never change its value
       currentprices = msg     # never being updated 
       print(currentprices)    # never printed


def getcurrentrates():
    print('get' + str(currentprices)) # printed
    print(type(currentprices)) # printed - ' dict '
    return currentprices       # returned with  initial value
```

Comment: Why do you think running this code "inside a class" prevents it from blocking your Flask app?

Comment: since it worked perfectly, i did some other test with threads but all other solutions --> either blocked the Flask(no response) or didn't work at all. This solution is working good but the as I mentioned --> even though the msg is consumed --> its never  being sent to the callback func.

Answer (score 0):

Since you define the **on_message_callback=self.callback**, you have to define the callback function as a **class method** with **self** as first function parameter as below

```
def callback(self, ch, method, properties, msg):
    ....
```